# Good option for CORS

Tags: javascript

I am creating a website that will run on mobile devices locally. I want to extract colors from a local image and show the colors on the website.

However, it returns a CORS error, since the image is on their devices and always in the same location with the same name (but the image changes every time).

What would be a good option to do this?

I tried/was thinking of the following ways:

- Upload the image to some website using an API and use the url it
  returns
- Try another libary (Couldn't find one that does not use getImageData)
- sourceImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous'); (didnt work)

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `website that will run on mobile devices locally` is this even a thing?

Comment: @Jaromanda X,  Depends of your definition of "Website". Lots of image/comic/video viewers run a website that runs on your local device. They show a URL, you visit the URL on your PC and upload files into the app. [eg](https://olimsoft.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/readme/)